# Commerce Product - show shipping category in template

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, ecommerce, shipping

I have setup some Shipping Categories (8 weeks, 4 weeks etc) and these appear down the side bar of a product when editing in admin next to 'Shipping' . How do i bring this value out via a tag on a product page/template?

Answer (score 2):

```
Product:<br>
Shipping Category: {{ product.shippingCategory.name ?? 'None' }}<br>
Tax Category: {{ product.taxCategory.name ?? 'None'}}<br>

Variant:<br>
Shipping Category: {{ variant.product.shippingCategory.name ?? 'None' }}<br>
Tax Category: {{ variant.product.taxCategory.name ?? 'None' }}<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

I took a guess and the answer was {{product.shippingCategory}}